# "one thousand feet" or "one thousand foot"

Tags: pronunciation

According to [a post](https://www.reddit.com/r/howyoudoin/comments/6h6506/in_55_rachel_says_she_thought_phoebe_would_be_the/)

[Phoebe](https://friends.fandom.com/wiki/Phoebe_Buffay) lives **less than 1000'** from the coffeehouse.

When speaking, should I pronounce **one thousand feet** or **one thousand foot**?

Answer (score 3):

Pronunciation of *foot* or of *feet* does not change significantly when embedded in a sentence. **However**, the *choice* of word depends on context, e.g.

> It is a **thousand-foot** drop to the bottom of the cliff
> It is a thousand **feet** to the bottom of the cliff.

In the first example, *thousand-foot* is used as an adjective, where it is regarded as a singular unit... as in the site [The 1,000-Foot View](https://www.strategyskills.com/1000-foot-view/).

In the second example, the noun, *feet*, must be plural.

Some more examples:

> "He has a thousand-mile stare," as opposed to, "She has a thousand miles to go."
> "It's a five-micron gap," as opposed to, "the gap is five microns."
> "It's a thousand-dollar bicycle," vs. "The bicycle is a thousand dollars."
> "Use a five-ohm resistor," but, "The resistor is five ohms."

*sigh*